# Change an existing Oracle APEX Report Layout RTF file

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've created a Report Query and a Report Layout in Oracle APEX. The Report Layout is an RTF type. I have uploaded a RTF template file to the layout upon defining it.

I would like to update the Report Layout.

It seems the only way to update the layout is to create a new Report Layout, and then update the Report Query to reference the new Report Layout.

With Oracle E-business Suite (EBS), there's an option to upload a replacement RTF file in the XML Template definition. Is that not an option in Oracle APEX?

Comment: Correct, you need to upload the new layout and modify the report Query to point to the new layout. Typically I would then delete the old report layout.